# Implicitly convert Oracle Date type to String using dataAdapter.Fill()

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, odp.net

I am currently using ODP.net to execute a large amount of SQL, and I am retrieving the data in a uniform way using an OracleDataAdapter, and the .Fill() method, as shown:

```
using (var oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(query, Connection))
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(oracleCommand);

    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

    var result = new List<T>();

    foreach (DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
        {
            var data = new T();
            foreach (DataColumn column in columns)
            {
                data[column.Ordinal] = row[column].ToString();
            }
            result.Add(data);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is that, as outlined here [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings), the OracleDataAdapter is implicitly converting my Date objects to .net DateTime which consequently puts the date in a different format.

The result is being put into a report thus it is important that it is represented as a String in the format that is output from the SQL server. Up until now I have simply been casting all results using the ToString() method as shown, but these dates are converted before this point.

The current solution is to use TO_CHAR on the script level, however this is not ideal, I would prefer not to have to change the SQL.

It is also not acceptable to write a method to try and parse any dates in C# as the SQL statements vary and each Date object could be under any column ordinal, so I would have to try and parse every single cell which I want to avoid entirely.

Cheers

Comment: `which consequently puts the date in a different format.` Dates in .NET don't have a format (they may be formatted when converted to a string, but that is a different thing). What makes you think it has a different format?

Comment: Dates and numbers have no format, they are binary values. *Don't* convert dates and numbers to strings at all. If you want to control how they are *displayed* set the format string on the form or control.

Comment: `TO_CHAR` isn't a solution, it's a *bug* on top of another bug. Return *dates* from Oracle, *ensure* they appear as DateTime objects in .NET, *never* convert them and store them as `datetime`, `date` or `datetime2` values in fields with the corresponding type in the database. *Neither* Oracle *nor* SQL Server have any date format.

Comment: It looks like this method is part of a generic class to convert a set of data into a list of T, sort of like a poor mans ORM. You're calling `ToString` on every type which is very bad for dates, and actually also for numbers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments a Date doesn't have a particular format. My issue was that I wanted the results as string literals, regardless of their type. Primarily because dataAdapter.Fill would remove any TimeZone related data by converting all TimeStamps (even TimeStampTZ) to DateTime objects. SafeMapping was a potential solution to get around this:

`adapter.SafeMapping.Add("*", typeof(string));`

however this was seemingly deprecated at some point and now throws an exception when used. My final solution was to use

`dataAdapter.ReturnProviderSpecificTypes = true;`

This allowed me to handle the Date types as their respective provider specific types thus I could intercept any OracleTimeStampTZ objects before they were implicitly converted to DateTime objects, as shown:

`public static string ConvertFormat(OracleTimeStampTZ ts)
{
            var TIME_ZONE = ((ts.GetTimeZoneOffset() < TimeSpan.Zero) ? "-" : "") + ts.GetTimeZoneOffset().ToString(@"hh\:mm");
            return ts.Value.ToString(NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT) + TIME_ZONE;
}`